# How long are the natural lifespans of the other aliens?

Tags: mass-effect-series

In the Mass Effect series, we learn that humans can now somehow live up to the age of 150, while special cases like Miranda can live even longer.

Asari can live up to a century and Salarians can only live for up to 40 human years.

But what about Krogans, Turians, Quarians and the other species mentioned?

Comment: The "Frog people" are called Drell. Though it's the Salarians that live around 40 years. Might be the case for both races though, not sure about the Drell.

Comment: edited. i really don't care about the drell and/or hanar tho

Comment: There's also the Volus, Protheans and the Elcor. Though I can imagine you don't really care about those either (Protheans are pretty interesting).

Comment: I thought asari lived a millenium? Perhaps I'm mistaken as I haven't played in a while.

Comment: I made some edits to clarify your question - however I've left the Asari lifespan as 'a century' as I can't recall if they do live up to a millennium as @sirdank mentioned. If so, please correct.

Comment: If this question doesn't cover every species am I allowed to make a question asking for the lifespans of the species which @ken is not interested in? What would I even title that question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't seem to care about all of the alien races I am just going to answer for the ones you mentioned in your question.

Sources are multiple discussions on forums, my own experience, and various wikis.

**Krogan**

The Mass Effect universe isn't very clear about how old Krogan can get. 
Almost all of them die while doing what they're good at (Mercenary work, fighting).

Okeer is probably the oldest Krogan you meet in the game. He has fought in the Krogan rebellion, which happened a long time before the events in Mass Effect. It is even said Wrex has fought there, meaning Wrex would be around 1000 years old. Wrex calls Okeer old, which means that Wrex with 1000 years old probably isn't considered old for Krogan standards. A fair age to guess for Okeer would be around 1800 years old. Even though Wrex called him old, it's not clear if he actually is nearing the end of his lifespan.

It's pretty safe to assume Krogan can live for thousands of years if they don't die by unnatural causes. They really are tough.

**Turians and Quarians**

Both the Turians and Quarians aren't very special compared to humans. Especially the Quarians aren't that different from humans (As mentioned by Tali).

While also here it doesn't seem like there is a confirmed max age, it's safe to assume they will live for around 150 years, just like humans. Quarians don't always reach this age though, because they are very vulnerable to infections. It's why they wear the suit after all.

**Vorcha**

Just something I came across during my search. Apperantly Vorcha only live up to 20 years.

Answer (score 1):

Asari can live Alot longer then a Century some live over a thousand years. Liara is over a hundred and is still considered a child of sorts.
Krogans can live up to 1,500 in some cases. 
Turians can reach 200 
While now a fair amount of humans reach upwards of 150
Quarians can reach 100-120
Salarians die around 40
Vorcha die about twenty years of age.
It is rare for Drell to even make 30 let alone 50
I'm not yet sure about Batarians,  Volus,  Hanar and Elcor.

Answer (score 1):

Asari can live for about 1000 years, Liara talked about her mother, a Matriarch being about that age I believe. Also Liara is 106, and she is considered a child. I am not sure about the human lifespan, but it seems around 150 is plausible. For salarians, I believe Mordin said that Salarians usually live no longer than 40. For Krogan, I believe a few centuries if my memory serves me well. As for turians, quarians, drell, elcor, hanar, volus, and vorcha I am not sure. But you can guess. Vorcha regenerate so they probably live long, quarians have envirosuits so they are less likely to disease, turians probably live longer due to advanced medicine similiar to humans. Drell, elcor, hanar, and volus probably don't live very long, though I am not sure.

TL:DR (Human 150) (Salarian 40) (Krogan a few centuries) (Asari around 1000 years) (Others unknown by me)

Answer (score 0):

Krogan live about as long as Asari naturally (if they don’t die prematurely during merc work) that’s why Asari more often seek out Krogan. Asari get actual life partners and Krogan get kids.

Answer (score 0):

I think Asari can live much longer them 1000 years. They become matriarchs around that age reaching their final "evolution". Although Liara's mother, for example, looked very far away to be near her death by natural causes; she was strong and healthy.